model.eval on pretrained YOLOv8 causes dowloading of datasets
I want to use pre-trained YOLOv8n. So after importing model I want to set it to eval mode (model.eval). However, instead of running the program as usual (which was the case when I didnt pu model.eval) it dowloads big dataset files.
Here are the folders and files that are dowloaded alongside code:

The files are so big that it takes forever to unzip.
Here is the code:
from ultralytics import YOLO
import torch
import logging

from detector.app import App
from detector.video_manager import VideoManager

class ImageProcessor:
    def __init__(self, parent_app: App, video_manager: VideoManager) -> None:
        logging.getLogger("ultralytics").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

        self._parent_app = parent_app
        self._video_manager = video_manager

        self._detector = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')
        device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        self._detector.to(device)

        print('Before eval')
        self._detector.eval()
        print('After eval') # does not execute - waits until everything is unzipped.

I do not think dowloading of these files is a normal behaviour.
Can you help?

Just for clarification, do you mean the coco2017labels-segments.zip?

Edit: My first statement was incorrect, I got your problem. Looking into it..

I found out why it downloads the dataset and posted about the issue on their github page. It's in my eyes just bad design. They have overwritten the model.train() call (which normally just switches the model into/out of training mode) with their own, which starts training now and by default downloads the coco dataset. But they do not handle what happens if another method like model.eval() calls model.train()..
I'm not sure how you want to run your model, but a solution could be to not call model.eval() and uses the model to predict like this:
image_processor = ImageProcessor()
with torch.no_grad():
    prediction = image_processor._detector(data)

The torch.no_grad() disables gradient computation, much like .eval() normally does. But only inside its context. Then the detector(data) call starts a normal prediction step without gradients.
You can also wrap that inside a function if you want. When using a function/method, you could also use the @torch.no_grad() decorator for it, it should do the same.
